# Exception error iOS

Tags: ios, exception

Hi folk I am trying to solve this error

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:  '    [<ProfiloViewController 0x8d54ec0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nomeTxt.'
```

[..]

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have not a method called setValue.. I can't figure out what's wrong

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occur when you are accessing `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` which is not properly connected to **File's Owner** so, First check your all the connections in Interface Builder OR *(Open the xib, select **File's Owner** and click on the "Connection Inspector")* Look at all outlets, any one has `!` ('s) that means it is missing outlet.

Comment: Yes, this is ok! thanks now it goes fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to you added an `IBOutlet` called `nomeTxt` and deleted it later. So that link might be broken now. Check your xib/storyboard connections.